# What would be the easiest route for creating permanent redirects to youtube based on user form input?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Say I have a site, we'll say fakesitename.com. I want users to be able to fill out a form with five inputs:

1. A Youtube video ID
2. A start time
3. An end time
4. An alias
5. A submit button

I'd like them to be able to submit this form, and for the site to create a redirect (preferably a 301 redirect, so I'm never technically hosting any content) from:

- fakesitename.com/[[input4]]

to

- Something like https://www.youtube.com/v/[[input1]]?hd=1&autoplay=1&start=[[input2]]&end=[[input3]]&version=3

What would be the best / easiest way to go about this? I'm not worried about handling the url layout generation, just writing the redirect.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well just use [header](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to send a `location` header

```
header('Location: http://www.youtube.com/?blabla', true, 301);
exit;
```